# Google Map Subgurim Show Arrowed Polyline

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, polyline, subgurim-maps

I am using Subgurim asp.net control for Google Maps in ASP.net.
The Problem is that I need to show an ARROWED POLYLINE betwwen my two points on map.

Following is my code , but unfortunately I am not able to apply anything for that:

```
GLatLng from = new GLatLng(FromLan, FromLon);
GLatLng To = new GLatLng(ToLan, ToLon);

GLatLngBounds llbound = new GLatLngBounds(from, To);

GMap2.GZoom = GMap2.getBoundsZoomLevel(llbound);
GMap2.setCenter(llbound.getCenter());


GLatLng inside = llbound.getCenter();
bool isInside = llbound.contains(inside);

GPolyline objpolyline = new GPolyline();
objpolyline.points.Add(from);
objpolyline.points.Add(To);
objpolyline.color = "red";
objpolyline.colorNet = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
objpolyline.clickable = false;
objpolyline.PolylineID = "Route";
objpolyline.geodesic = true;
//Javascript Code
//pts1.push (new GLatLng(lat111, lng222));
//var poly1 =  new BDCCArrowedPolyline(pts1,"#FF0000",4,0.3,
//                                       null,30,7,"#0000FF",2,0.5);
//map.addOverlay(poly1);

GMap2.addPolyline(objpolyline);
//GMap2.addPolyline(objpolyline);
```

Regards ,
Vishal

Comment: Where are you stuck? Is the polyline displayed?

Comment: yes , the polyline is displayed between the points but it should show the Arrows on the line to show the navigation direction of the journey between points.

Comment: I doubt there is no such functionality in the subgurim control to get an arrow with the polyline. Correct me if I am wrong. I dint find it in its website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using the Google Maps API v2.

Two issues with that:

1. it is deprecated and could stop working in less than a year.
2. the Google Maps API v3 now supports ["arrowed polylines"](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-symbol-arrow) natively.